# Kotlin: unresolved reference for Updating UI using Observables

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am learning kotlin and databinding for android. I am able to run function of databinding. While I am working with Observable, I am getting unresolve reference for `BR.property`

here is my `model class`:

```
data class FruitModel(var fruitImage: String?, var fruitName: String?) : BaseObservable() {


var imageUrl: String? = fruitImage
    get() = field
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.imageUrl)
    }

var nameValue: String? = fruitName
    get() = field
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.fruitModel)
    }
```

}

I am able to get `BR.fruitModel` instead of above two. Here is my `xml`:

```
<data>

    <variable name="onClickItem"
              type="com.wings.kotlintest1.interfaces.FruitAdapterInterface"/>

    <variable name="fruitModel"
              type="com.wings.kotlintest1.model.FruitModel"/>

    <variable name="position"
              type="int"/>

</data>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            android:onClick="@{() -> onClickItem.onClickItemListener(position)}">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivFruitImage"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    app:loadImageWithGlide="@{fruitModel.fruitImage}"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFruitName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="@{fruitModel.fruitName}"/>


        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

> what is reason that BR class is not generating properties? Am I doing
>   something wrong?

Comment: After adding @Bindable and Rebuild I am able to get that properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the @Bindable property to the get() of those fields.  See 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `@get:Bindable`

```
data class FruitModel(var fruitImage: String?, var fruitName: String?) : BaseObservable() {

    @get:Bindable
    var imageUrl: String? = fruitImage
        get() = field
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.imageUrl) // **unresolved reference : BR.imageUrl**
        }

    @get:Bindable
    var nameValue: String? = fruitName
        get() = field
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.nameValue) // **unresolved reference : BR.nameValue**
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your full layout must be inside `<layout> ... </layout>`.
Also, try to clean and build your project.
You can also trace your wrong line in stacktrace under build window.

Comment: already included <layout> and tried with clean project. it is not working.